# Include appropriate superscripts when labeling table headers

Tags: r, rscript

I am attempting to format a simple table showing displacement and speed values. These, of course, have units with superscripts. In my case, displacement as mm^2 and speed as mm^-1. I found one solution to writing mm^2, shown below in the code, but I cannot figure out how to write -1 in superscript. What I've done so far is use the ^ as a placeholder. I'm betting there is a much easier way to superscript any value, but I cannot find it on trusty ole' google. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
'colnames(reduced.rounded.summary) <- c("Handling Time", "Capture", 
                                       "Total Copepod Displacement (mm\u00B2)", 
                                       "Average Copepod Speed (mm^-1)", 
                                       "Maximum Copepod Speed (mm^-1)", 
                                       "Total Mouth Displacement (mm\u00B2)", 
                                       "Average Mouth Speed (mm^-1)",
                                       "Maximum Mouth Speed (mm^-1)")'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```r
c("Handling Time", "Capture", 
  "Total Copepod Displacement (mm\u00B2)", 
  "Average Copepod Speed (mm\u207b\u00B9)", 
  "Maximum Copepod Speed (mm\u207b\u00B9)", 
  "Total Mouth Displacement (mm\u00B2)", 
  "Average Mouth Speed (mm\u207b\u00B9)",
  "Maximum Mouth Speed (mm\u207b\u00B9)")

#> [1] "Handling Time"                    "Capture"                         
#> [3] "Total Copepod Displacement (mm²)" "Average Copepod Speed (mm⁻¹)"    
#> [5] "Maximum Copepod Speed (mm⁻¹)"     "Total Mouth Displacement (mm²)"  
#> [7] "Average Mouth Speed (mm⁻¹)"       "Maximum Mouth Speed (mm⁻¹)"
```

Comment: Allan, you just saved me many hours of searching and many tears. Thank you so very much!